# Solve $\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{y}{x} = \frac{1}{(1+\log x+\log y)^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

> Solve $\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{y}{x} = \frac{1}{(1+\log x+\log y)^2}$

I tried solving this differential equation, I got stuck after a few steps
I got 
$(a+\log(xy))^2d(xy) = xdx$
I don't know what to do after this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write $$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{y}{x} = \frac{1}{(1+\log(xy))^2}$$ and substitute $v=xy$, then wonderful things happen.  Then $$\frac{dv}{dx} = x\frac{dy}{dx} +y$$ Plug stuff in and the equation becomes $$\frac{1}{x}\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{1}{(1+\log v)^2},$$ separable.

Answer (score 0):

Taking L.C.M on the left side you'll get 
$$ (xdy + ydx )(1+logxy)^2 = xdx $$
And as we know that $$xdy + ydx = d(xy)$$ so by substituting $$xy=t$$ you'll get
$$(1+logt)^2 dt = xdx $$
Integrating both sides
$$ \int (1+logt)^2 \mathrm{d}t =  (x^2 )/2 + c$$
To solve the L.H.S use your own integration skills (Hint :- Integration by parts )

Answer (score -1):

With $u = xy$, the differential equation becomes
separable.

Comment: Why the downvote?